# Setting up port forwarding via UPnP on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, port, port-forwarding, site-to-site-vpn, upnp

I'd like to set up some port forwarding in our router, using UPnP.

More specifically, I want to run some program on startup that always forwards port 8443 my IP address (192.168.1.100). Port 8443 is for our SVN server.

How do I do this with Windows Server 2008 R2?

(I don't want to go into the router to set up port forwarding, as everytime I do this, the router resets itself and we lose the internet connection for 5 minutes which plays havoc with everything else on the network)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vba program listed at [Programmatically Controlling a UPnP-Capable Firewall](http://www.knoxscape.com/Upnp/NAT.htm) runs under Windows XP.  I have not tried it on a server but it's worth a try.  Even if it doesn't work, the references may lead you in the right direction.